# How to transfer wei from a contract to a specific address?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapp-development, addresses, payable

I was making an auction system and I wanted to make sure that when someone bid higher the contract would return the money to the address of the previous bid.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

contract simpleAuction{
    uint currentValue = 0;
    address buyer;

    function set() public payable{
        uint sent = msg.value;
        require(sent>currentValue, "Bid less than current value.");

        buyer.transfer(currentValue);

        currentValue = sent;
        buyer = msg.sender;
    }

    function winner() public view returns (address addressWinner, uint newValue){
        addressWinner = buyer;
        newValue = currentValue;
    }
}
```

The error is in the line `buyer.transfer (currentValue);` that in case `transfer()` only works for `msg.sender`.

Comment: I think buyer should be a payable address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Solidity 0.5.0 or greater, you will need to make `buyer` a `payable` address. You can do this by adding `payable` to the `buyer` declaration:

`address payable buyer;`